# approximating sum by integral

Tags: integration, summation

There's a term as  $k^\phi \sum_{j=1}^k{1\over j^\phi}$.
This sum is approximated by the integral
$k^\phi(1+\int_0^{k}{1\over(1+x)^\phi}dx)$.

Can someone please tell me how this approximation is made.

Comment: This is classical: divide the interval $[0,k]$ into $k$ intervals of length $1$ each and look at lower and upper Darboux sums of the integral.

Comment: @uniquesolution Can you please explain it a bit more as I don't know what Darboux sums of the integral means